# Mongoose schema how to add an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was wondering how can we add an array of string in a moongoose schema.

I have the following code but it is not working:

```
var message = new Schema({
    topic: String,
    content: String,
    restriction:String,
    sender:String,
    reciever:String,
    users:[String],
    read:{type: String, default: 'no'},
    like:{ type: Number, default: 0 },
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

I am talking about `users`. Can you help?

Comment: per the docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html `users: [String]` works fine as you've written it.  Can you expound a little on what's not working with your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cobbling together what you said in your comments and the main post, I can't help but think you're missing the modeling step of mongoose.

First you define the schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MessageSchema = new Schema({
    topic: String,
    content: String,
    restriction:String,
    sender:String,
    reciever:String,
    users:[String],
    read:{type: String, default: 'no'},
    like:{ type: Number, default: 0 },
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

Then you have to tell mongoose about it:

```
const Message = mongoose.model('Message', MessageSchema);
```

Then you can create an instance to put data into:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb'); // assuming that's a working mongo instance
let message = new Message();
message.users.push('Juliana');
message.save((e,u) => { console.log('New user saved!'); });
```

If I'm wrong, please post more info about what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
var message = new Schema({
      topic: String,
      content: String,
      restriction:String,
      sender:String,
      reciever:String,
      users:[{
        type: String
      }],
      read:{type: String, default: 'no'},
      like:{ type: Number, default: 0 },
      created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var message = new Schema({
      topic: String,
      content: String,
      restriction:String,
      sender:String,
      reciever:String,
      users:[
      {name: String}],
      read:{type: String, default: 'no'},
      like:{ type: Number, default: 0 },
      created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}

    });
```

Comment: Many thanks can u show me how to update the field. Lets say i want to add a new user is it like this : `message.users.push(newUsr)`;